# how to create server program to connect iphone app to computer via wifi?

Tags: iphone

For example:

> Download Touch Mouse in two-steps:
>   1) Get the Touch Mouse App for your iPhone or iPod touch from the App Store
>   2) Download Touch Mouse Server software and install it on your computer.
>   You’ll find instructions when you download the Touch Mouse Server software on Logitech.com.

if I want to use Logitech "Touch Mouse" app, I have to install "Touch Mouse Server software" on my computer
I want to create a server software like this,,, any suggestions ???
please help me !!!
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in three simple steps:

- Open Xcode
- Click on `Help` in the menu and then on `Developer Documentation`
- Search for `Bonjour`
- **Read** the documentation and analyze some of the sample code and
  start off with a simple Bonjour test.

Seriously, you can't expect from yourself nor anyone else to start off with no knowledge about a technology/idea and just start coding. All takes time, innovation and experience. So before you start something sophisticated, do the steps above.

After all, Rome wasn't built in a day.

Comment: Mark my answer as the right one by clicking on the green checkmark! :)